# HTML5 canvas text orientation circle inside wheel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, text, rotation

https://jsfiddle.net/5e7hwn8m/

Hi, I am trying to set a wheel with numbers and then inside selected ones identified from A to F (A, B, C, D, E and F).

The issue is A-F are are rotating like numbers, I don't want that and I can't seem to figure what to do to have them Facing my direction.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? jsfiddle code for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/5e7hwn8m/

```js
var wheelNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"];
//16 20 18 55 5 25
var wheelABCDEF = ["", "", "", "", "E", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "A", "", "C", "",
  "B", "", "", "", "", "F", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", ""
];


var backgroundColours = ["#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#005def", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#005def", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#005def", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb"];
var startAngle = 4.7;
var arc = Math.PI / (wheelNumbers.length / 2);


var ctx;

function drawWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;

  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 150;
    var insideRadius = 120;
    var textRadius = 160;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);

    //ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.8;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for (var i = 0; i < wheelNumbers.length; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColours[i];

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(200, 200, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(200, 200, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
      //
      ctx.save();
      //ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      //ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      //ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      //ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      //'#005def'
      ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
      ctx.translate(200 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 200 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = wheelNumbers[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);

      text = wheelABCDEF[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = '#005def';

      ctx.rotate(0);
      ctx.fillText(text, 0, 60);


      ctx.restore();

    }

  }
}



drawWheel();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure if this is what you are asking. I am calculating the point where the letter should apear and I'm painting the letter without rotating.
In the code I've marked the changes I've made.

```js
var wheelNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"];
//16 20 18 55 5 25
var wheelABCDEF = ["", "", "", "", "E", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "A", "", "C", "",
  "B", "", "", "", "", "F", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", ""
];


var backgroundColours = ["#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#005def", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#005def", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#005def", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb"];
var startAngle = 4.7;
var arc = Math.PI / (wheelNumbers.length / 2);


var ctx;

function drawWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;

  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 150;
    var insideRadius = 120;
    var textRadius = 160;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);

    //ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.8;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for (var i = 0; i < wheelNumbers.length; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColours[i];

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(200, 200, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(200, 200, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
      //
      ctx.save();
      //ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      //ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      //ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      //ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      //'#005def'
      ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
      
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // calculating the position for the letter
      var x = 200 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * 100;
      var y = 200 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * 100;
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////
      
      ctx.translate(200 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 200 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = wheelNumbers[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      ctx.restore();// restore goes here
      
      
      text = wheelABCDEF[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = '#005def';

      // paint the letter  without rotating
      ctx.fillText(text, x, y);


      

    }

  }
}



drawWheel();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I'm glad it works @user4561667. In this case would you consider accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

One way could do so would be by rendering your letters after your wheel.

You determine the angle the are at on the wheel using their position in your array.
than using cos and sin find their position in pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that *ctx.rotate()* is relative to the current matrix transform, or if you will, to the current angle of rotation.

This means that your `rotate(0)` will do nothing. What you want is `rotate( -currentAngle )`.
But before to call it, you'd have to set your text's position as the pivot of the rotation, i.e as the origin of our transform matrix, and this can be done by calling `ctx.translate(text_x, text_x)`, and since we are now at the text position, we can call fillText with 0, 0 parameters:

```
// set the origin to the text's position
ctx.translate(0,60);
// reverse rotate
ctx.rotate(-currentAngle);
// draw at origin (0,0)
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
```

```js
var wheelNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"];
//16 20 18 55 5 25
var wheelABCDEF = ["", "", "", "", "E", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "A", "", "C", "",
  "B", "", "", "", "", "F", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", "", "", "", "D", "", "", "", ""
];


var backgroundColours = ["#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#005def", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#ffff00", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#66ffff", "#005def", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#005def", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#c0c0c0", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#33cc33", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ff99ff", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#005def", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb", "#ffffbb"];
var startAngle = 4.7;
var arc = Math.PI / (wheelNumbers.length / 2);


var ctx;

function drawWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;

  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 150;
    var insideRadius = 120;
    var textRadius = 160;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);

    //ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.8;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for (var i = 0; i < wheelNumbers.length; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColours[i];

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(200, 200, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(200, 200, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
      //
      ctx.save();
      //ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      //ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      //ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      //ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      //'#005def'
      ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
      ctx.translate(200 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 200 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
/* BEGIN EDIT*/
      // save the currentAngle in a variable
      var currentAngle = angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2;
      ctx.rotate(currentAngle);
      var text = wheelNumbers[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);

      text = wheelABCDEF[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = '#005def';
      // set the origin to the text's position
      ctx.translate(0,60);
      // reverse rotate
      ctx.rotate(-currentAngle);
      // draw at origin (0,0)
      ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
/* END EDIT*/
      ctx.restore();

    }

  }
}



drawWheel();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```